# How to sync my own calendar with my phone (iPhone, Android, etc)

Tags: php, android, iphone, ios, calendar

I created a portal for my company.

In this portal, we have to login and once we are in, we can manage our calendars and events. I would like to know how I can sync this with the iOS and/or the Android ?

Do I need to create an app for it or I can create a module so I can add a protocol to my website ? Google Calendar can sync with the iPhone, he must use a sort of protocol or it is build-in ?

Any ideas ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple options.  The simplest would probably be to add support for the Internet Calendar Format (.ics) and build your calendar to support subscriptions.  Android and iOS both support internet calendars.  [Here's the Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) for ics.  It's definitely not enough to implement a connector for, but it should be a good place to get started.